# SQL Server : confusion with left an right join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm slightly confused with SSMS (Version 18 or 19 doesn't matter).
I try to create a query with some joins.

I wrote this statement:

```
SELECT        
    Beleg.fibu_beleg_id
FROM
    integris.fibu_beleg AS Beleg 
INNER JOIN
    integris.periode AS Periode ON Beleg.periode_id = Periode.periode_id 
INNER JOIN
    integris.belegart ON Beleg.belegart_id = integris.belegart.belegart_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.fibu_belegpos AS BelegPos ON Beleg.fibu_beleg_id = BelegPos.fibu_beleg_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.sachkonto AS Sachkonto ON Sachkonto.sachkonto_id = BelegPos.sachkonto_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.steuerschl ON BelegPos.steuerschl_id = integris.steuerschl.steuerschl_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.buchungsschl ON BelegPos.buchungsschl_nr = integris.buchungsschl.nummer 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.personenkonto ON BelegPos.personenkonto_id = integris.personenkonto.personenkonto_id 
INNER JOIN
    integris.konto ON integris.personenkonto.personenkonto_id = integris.konto.personenkonto_id
WHERE        
    (YEAR(Periode.von_dat) >= YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 2)
```

If I run this query, I get approx. 400.000 rows. But I'm expecting around 900.000

I then copy-pasted this code inside the a new view (View_1) so I see the tables and joins and everything seems fine.

After I change one join by right click on the join between `BelegPos` and `personenkonto` to change it to an inner join and then back to include all from `BelegPos` the query changes to

```
SELECT        
    Beleg.fibu_beleg_id
FROM
    integris.personenkonto 
INNER JOIN
    integris.konto ON integris.personenkonto.personenkonto_id = integris.konto.personenkonto_id 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    integris.fibu_belegpos AS BelegPos ON integris.personenkonto.personenkonto_id = BelegPos.personenkonto_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.fibu_beleg AS Beleg 
INNER JOIN
    integris.periode AS Periode ON Beleg.periode_id = Periode.periode_id 
INNER JOIN
    integris.belegart ON Beleg.belegart_id = integris.belegart.belegart_id 
    ON BelegPos.fibu_beleg_id = Beleg.fibu_beleg_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.sachkonto AS Sachkonto ON Sachkonto.sachkonto_id = BelegPos.sachkonto_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    integris.steuerschl ON BelegPos.steuerschl_id = integris.steuerschl.steuerschl_id 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    integris.buchungsschl ON BelegPos.buchungsschl_nr = integris.buchungsschl.nummer
WHERE
    (YEAR(Periode.von_dat) >= YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 2)
```

and I get back the 900.000 records I need to see.

I honestly don't understand why my first attempt doesn't return all the records I need since left and right join are interchangable if done right.

And since SMSS shows all tables and joins as I intended them to be AND both queries render the same SQL diagram I don't really understand what's wrong with my attempt.

I assume, that somehow the left join between `BelegPos` and `personenkonto` does not work the way i thought it would. Is this a bug or am I stupid?

Comment: Telling us you use SSMS is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some; alarming from a mechanic.

Comment: Also, I know it's common in some places, but I cringe every time I see the JOIN statements at the end of the line instead of the beginning

Comment: Okay... does it help if i say its an SQL Server Standard Version 13.0.1742?
And yes, i hate how this is formatted but since this is the way SMSS formats this i did not bother to change it.

Comment: Yes, that is much better. Better still would be telling us "SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition"

Comment: *"does it help if i say its an SQL Server Standard Version 13.0.1742?"* It does. Though you're missing quite a few SP's and Security patches; that build was released back in August 2017.

Comment: When you use `INNER JOIN` **after** `OUTER JOIN` you effectively negate the ***outer*** part.

Comment: i would avoid the right joins altogether and try to get the first version to work. You have `LEFT JOIN ON personenkonto` but after you run `INNER JOIN ON personenkonto`, this kinda changes the first JOIN to INNER as well. Probably easiest to change to `LEFT JOIN integris.konto` but it's hard to say since you're the only one who knows how the data is structured.

Comment: INNER JOIN removes rows on a non-joining condition; so if you're expecting more rows then that might be why.

Comment: The second query seems incorrect since there is 2 "ON" clauses within one join (`INNER JOIN integris.belegart ON ... ON ...`). Also the easiest way to investigate is to run the query using only inner joins and then change them one by one to left joins in subsqeuent runs(Im assuming the query runtime isn't too long).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, joins....

This does not have any issues with right or left, or any other joins.... This is issue about point of view.

For example, very classic example: you have customers in the table `customers` and orders in the table `orders`.
You want to know, how many customers in your database.
Which is very simple:

```sql
select   count(1)
from     customers
```

Ok, let's pretend that you have 1000 customers in your database.
Now, you want to know, how many customers have at lest one order, and how many customers have no orders, and you try to write something like this:

```sql
select   c.customer_id
         , count(1)
from     customers c
         inner join orders o on o.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

And you can see, that all these customers have orders, but now you have only 983 customers in your table.
The reason of this situation is filtering of tables, because you try to use `inner join`. Result of query shows you only those rows, which persists in both tables.
But, that if you want to get information about all customers, even for those, who don't have orders?
You can rewrite query:

```sql
select   c.customer_id
         , count(1)
from     customers c
         left join orders o on o.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Just use `left join`, and you again have 1000 customers in your table, but in this case some of them have 0 orders.
Ok, all this very interesting, but very confusing, how about topic of the question?
Let's check this example:

```sql
select   c.customer_id
         , count(1)
from     orders o 
         right join customers c on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
```

This query provide the same result, but.... we have two differences:

1. we have right join instead of left join
2. we have another order of the tables in the `from` statement.

So, as result we can interpretier joins by this way:
`show me all data from the left/right table, but particular data from join table`

Let's try to apply this to my examples:

Query 1:

```sql
select   c.customer_id
         , count(1)
from     customers c
         left join orders o on o.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Translation:

```
sql server, please show me all rows from the left table (customer) 
and fill order's data only for those records, which exist in the order table.
```

Query 2:

```sql
select   c.customer_id
         , count(1)
from     orders o 
         right join customers c on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
```

Translation:

```
sql server, please show me all rows from the right table (customer) 
and fill order's data only for those records, which exist in the order table.
```

This is reason, why I am not recomment use right joins - it is very confusing.
It will be better to start `from` statement from those table, where you need to view all rows, and after in try to include to the result all other tables step-by-step by `left join`.